# Call MS SQL Server Stored Procedure with multiple parameters inclusive of table-value parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

After doing some research here and online I am at a loss as to whether this is possible.  What I want to do is call a stored procedure that has several parameters one of which is a table-value parameter.

This is my stored procedure snippet:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[procName]
@Action nvarchar(10) = 'view'
,@var1 int = 0
,@var2 int = 0
,@var3 myType ReadOnly
```

I now have another procedure (proc2) that has the following lines:

```
    insert into @varX
    select top 5
        field1, field2
    from
        sourceTable
print 'Processing from table values...'
exec dbo.procName  'refresh', -1, 0, @varX
```

Note that varX and var3 are of the same type MyType
When I execute proc2 I get the error that I am specifying too many arguments for dbo.procName

I am at the point in thinking it is not possible to specify multiple parameters inclusive of a table-value parameter to a stored procedure.  I am now tending towards the thought of changing my procName definition to only have one parameter (as all of the examples online seem to have) and have my table-value paramter act as an array of parameter values inclusive of the information I had in my previous select statement (in proc2). If however it is possible to do this call, please illustrate how this is done.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you explicitly name your parameters (which is good practice anyway)? `exec dbo.procName @Action = 'refresh'` etc. The error message you're getting is usually a result of a coding error or typo and explicitly naming the parameters is a good way to uncover that. As Damien suggests, you can also try to recreate this error with some test code as he did; if you can't reproduce the error then something is probably wrong with your calling code. If you really can't find anything, then using SQL Profiler to check the code being executed may help.

Comment: @Pondlife yes I can recreate the error and I was previously explicitly naming my parameters.  If you try the example where your first parameter is nvarchar and then your tvp and other parameters, you'll get the error too

Comment: Can you copy and paste your standalone test script - like the one in Damien's answer - that re-creates the error, so others can copy and paste it into SSMS and try it?

Comment: @Pondlife unfortunately no - I've come up with a workaround which was to create another SP that accepts only the TVP and another that accepts all INTs and the TVP.  That works.  In the case of the NVARCHARs and then getting the error of specifying too many arguments (even though they are named) still is baffling.  I'll research once I'm finished with the project and comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiles and runs for me:

```
create type TT as table (ID int not null);
go
create procedure P1
    @Val1 int,
    @Val2 TT readonly,
    @Val3 int
as
    select @Val1 as Val1,ID,@Val3
    from @Val2;
go
create procedure P2
as
    declare @T TT;
    insert into @T(ID) values (1),(2)

    exec P1 10,@T,13
go
exec P2
```

Result:

```
Val1        ID          
----------- ----------- -----------
10          1           13
10          2           13
```

So, I don't know what your issue is, but it's not being able to mix table and non-table parameters.

Comment: Thanks Damien, thanks for the reply but do entertain me and default the parameters.  That's the only difference I'm seeing in your answer (apart from placement of the table-value parameter - but I think that's a non-issue). I don't know if this is something to consider but I altered the stored procedure and then added the table-value parameter.

Comment: @Amd4632 - yep, works fine if the non-table parameters have defaults. I wrote the original and tried it out in about 5 minutes. I updated it to have defaults and ran it again in ~2 minutes. These aren't complex or expensive tests - if you don't have a scratch server (running Express or Developer Edition) I'd highly recommend it.